# using a for and an if loop in bash script

Tags: php, linux, bash, if-statement, for-loop

i am trying to create a bash script which prints odd numbers from 1-99
my logic works in php but i cant figure out what the code will be in bash

php code:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=99; $i++)
{
if ( $i % 2 != 0 )
{
echo "$i <br>";
}
}
```

how do i convert it into bash

i tried the following but it dint work

```
for ((i=1; i<=99; i++))
do
if [ $i % 2 != 0 ]
then
echo "$i";
fi
done
```

the result is like
~ no response on stdout ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is your `if` statement. If you are using bash, you can take advantage of the `(( ))` syntax here too:

```
if (( i % 2 != 0 )); then echo "$i"; fi
```

You will often find that people write this using `&&` too:

```
(( i % 2 != 0 )) && echo "$i"
```

This version is most faithful to the original, in that you are incrementing the counter `i` by one per iteration but you could of course simplify the code to increment by 2:

```
for ((i=1; i<=99; i+=2))
```

You could even skip the loop entirely:

```
printf "%s\n" {1..99..2}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a condition:

```
for i in {1..99..2} ; do
    echo $i
done
```

To use the condition with the modulo operator, use arithmetic condition:

```
 if (( i % 2 != 0 )) ; then
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..99}
do
    j=$(echo "$i % 2" | bc)
    if [[ $j -ne 0 ]]
    then
        echo $i
    fi
done
```